# Payload size limit - Logic Apps to Functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I've hit a limitation with Logic Apps that is causing me grief with my client. I
am finding that my payload from Logic Apps to Azure Functions cannot exceed
~15MB. That is way too small a limit in this day and age.

This page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config
says "Message size  50 MB   Some connectors and APIs may not support 50MB".

My tests show that the limit to Azure Functions is about 15MB. Is there any solution path for processing larger files? Any chance that the limit could be increased to 50MB? That would cover my needs.

Comment: what did you end up doing?

Comment: what happen next? is it wokring?

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned the file size that Logic Apps passes through a workflow is 50MB.  I'll let the Azure Functions team chime in on any potential limit on the webhook payload, but if it is possible I'll make sure we create a work item to increase to whatever Azure Functions supports.

-
Jeff - Azure Logic Apps team

Comment: Best place to reach out to the team is https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion for workaround- how about have the payload upload to a blob separately inside the logic app, then pass the link to the data file to AzFn and let it fetch there? Would be ideal if MS fix it quick but maybe you need a workaround?